# User on the desktop has delayed keyboard response, but not when in the login screen, a different user, or in the admin command prompt

Tags: windows, keyboard, hardware-failure, lag, delay

I have this very peculiar issue where when I think my PC was reaching the limit on memory usage, something suddenly happened causing keyboard input lag, yet when I opened up command prompt as an administrator to do a healthcheck using dism.exe, there was no delay at all typing the command, I had also tried to reupdate my keyboard drives to no avail. The keyboard works completely fine on the windows lock screen too, and when I login to a different user (which I am on right now) the keyboard works completely fine. This is not a hardware issue but more so that something on my original user account is making me type really delayed. On top of this, even the onscreen keyboard will be delayed. This issue does not affect my mouse at all. I could easily just restart my computer to try to fix this issue but it could also be helpful to see what is causing this issue. I checked my keyboard settings and it said my filter keys were off too.

Comment: If it's only one specific user could the solution be to delete that user and have them log in fresh? After backing up any data of course.

Comment: Update: this issue happened to me again and it was because I was using ram at max capacity (according to resource monitor)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my HP laptop starting about 12 Sept except both keyboard and mouse input were extremely laggy for standard user accounts. My administrator account was not impacted and when I temporarily elevated the standard user accounts to administrators, the problem goes away. It's only input in the user session that is impacted; not present when on the lock screen or login screen. I also noticed frequent (multiple per second) successful security audit messages about enumerating the Credential Store in the Event Log but this was also happening for my admin account.

I have performed a system restore to 5 days ago and the problem went away. I have temporarily paused updates in hopes Microsoft finds and fixes the issue.

Two recent updates that were rolled back:

- **KB5030219** Win 11 22H2 cumulative update -- potential culprit
- KB5031217 .NET Framework update

See Microsoft thread commenting on HP Omen Gaming Hub: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_11-wintop_update/standard-users-lag-upon-login-since-september-12